# Error: spawn EMFILE Node js

Tags: node.js, child-process

I am getting this error. While a person logs in to the application, logs are entered into a file using utilityWrapper. This file is read/Written when ever some activity is happening in the application. Then suddenly after some time

```
'throw errnoException(process._errno, 'spawn');
Error: spawn EMFILE
    at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:935:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:723:9)
    at Object.Logger (/web/utilityWrapper.js:21:17)
    at process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED (/web/server.js:141:17)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at process._fatalException (node.js:272:26)
```

This error come up.
Please Help me.

Comment: EMFILE usually means that your host machine has run out of available sockets (which is similar to simultaneously opened files in the system). This error is not directly related to NodeJS, but to UNIX. More on this here: http://blog.izs.me/post/56827866110/wtf-is-emfile-and-why-does-it-happen-to-me.

If, however, it happens on pure system, without any special config to `ulimit`, I'd suspect that you possibly open files recursively or in a loop somewhere in the code and this loop does not have stop condition (hence your Node.JS process opens too many files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This had happened due to various reasons. The code had many console.logs, which was printing many things on the command prompt on which the server was running. As it was writing to a file, it was using a file descriptor(`fd`). The `ulimit` of file descriptor is 1024. 
using the command

```
lsof - -i -n  -P | grep nodejs
```

I was able to capture the information about each `fd`.
`Fd` count used to increase when a user loogged into the application.The ldap sockets and mysql db connections also consumed  a large amount of `fd`'s.
So guys keep these points in mind when you get this kind of Error.